# Custom tool error when adding service refrence

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

Hi First of all sorry if this is a duplicated question but I read nearly all articles in stackoverflow and msdn about this problem and still no luck.  I'm developing an application in c# (WinForm) and I want to use a web service to retrieve some information. They gave me a WSDL file and I tried to add a service reference to my project but I got this warnings and an error: (I also unchecked "reuse types in referenced assemblies")

> Warning 3 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
>   Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: The datatype 'urn:tvtowsdl:gavahiRow' is missing.
>
> Warning 5 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
>   Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
>   XPath to wsdl:binding
>
> Warning   4   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
>   Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
>   XPath to wsdl:portType
>
> Error 6   Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'ServiceReference1'

I assumed I might going the wrong direction then I tried to add Web reference and I got these two errors:

> Error 1   Custom tool error: Unable to import WebService/Schema. Unable to import binding 'tvtowsdlBinding' from namespace 'urn:tvtowsdl'. Unable to import operation 'getGavahi'. The datatype 'urn:tvtowsdl:gavahiRow' is missing.
>   Error 2   Custom tool error: Unable to import WebService/Schema. Unable to import binding 'tvtowsdlBinding' from namespace 'urn:tvtowsdl'. Unable to import operation 'getGavahi'. The datatype 'urn:tvtowsdl:gavahiRow' is missing.

Am I missing something ?I'm using Visual Studio 2012. Please help me.[This is the wsdl file](http://www.portaltvto.com/index.php/azmoonse/electronic_gavahi_srv/getstudent?wsdl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the problem. So simple.I chose the  `collection type` to `System.ComonentModelBindinglist` and that's it . No error.